# printing img tag using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to print a barcode that i have generated using a jQuery plugin but i am unable to print the said barcode.

```
    <form class="row g-3 mt-5 mb-5 p-5">
        
        <div class="col-auto">
          <label for="inputPassword2" class="visually-hidden">Password</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputPassword2"  placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-auto">
          <button type="button" onclick="generatebar()" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Generate barcode</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div class="barcode_content" style="width: 38mm; height: 25mm;">
        <p>Title of Barcode </p>
        <img id="barcode_id" />
      </div>

    <script src="assets/jquery.js></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.0/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
   <script>
function generatebar() {
    var sdeec = document.getElementById('inputPassword2').value;

    JsBarcode("#barcode_id", sdeec, {
        format: "CODE39",
        width:1,
        height:40,
        font: "monospace",
        displayValue: false,
        lineColor: "#000000"
    });

    pwin = window.open(document.getElementById("barcode_id").src,"_blank");
  pwin.onload = function () {window.print();}

}
</script>
```

so what i am doing hear is using the jsbarcode plugin for generating the barcode and the barcode value is taken from input field with id inputPassword2 and putting it in the img tag with id barcode_id then i found a code to print the image tag but it is not working, Any help is appreciated

Comment: If this is a copy/paste of your code, you're missing the closing `"` on your jquery reference line...  `<script src="assets/jquery.js></script>`

Comment: no i actually wrote hear so i missed it

Comment: OK, no problem. FYI, "hear" is what you do with your ears... you mean "here"

Answer (score 1):

i was able to come with a solution and it works i hope someone finds it helping

i started bu adding a button with an onclick function

```
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-3 mb-3 col-12" onclick="print_barcode()">Print</button>
```

then i used the below js

```
function print_barcode(){
    var image = document.getElementById('barcode_id');
    printImage(image);
}


function printImage(image)
{
        var printWindow = window.open('', 'Print Window', 'height=400,width=600');
        printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Print Window</title>');
        printWindow.document.write('</head><body ><img src=\'');
        printWindow.document.write(image.src);
        printWindow.document.write('\' /></body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
}
```

and it works.